# Changing None values in a list to previous elements in the list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I scraped some dates off a website and threw them in a list.

```
dates = ['Jun-29-20', 'None', 'None', 'Jun-27-20', 'Jun-26-20', 'None', 'Jun-24-20', 'Jun-22-20', 'None', 'Jun-17-20', 'Jun-16-20', 'None', 'Jun-15-20', 'None', 'None', 'Jun-01-20', 'None', 'May-29-20', 'May-15-20', 'May-11-20', 'May-08-20', 'Apr-02-20', 'Feb-28-20', 'Feb-24-20', 'Feb-18-20', 'Feb-13-20', 'Jan-19-20', 'Jan-17-20']
```

When I go to format the dates in pandas using `df_news['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df_news['Dates'], errors='ignore').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` I of course receive an error because `strftime` doesnt accept anything but datetime data type.

I'd like to replace the 'None' elements in the list with the previous date elements prior to putting it in a dataframe, so it would look like this.

```
dates = ['Jun-29-20', 'Jun-29-20', 'Jun-29-20', 'Jun-27-20', 'Jun-26-20', 'Jun-26-20', 'Jun-24-20', 'Jun-22-20', 'Jun-22-20', 'Jun-17-20', 'Jun-16-20', 'Jun-16-20', 'Jun-15-20', 'Jun-15-20', 'Jun-15-20', 'Jun-01-20', 'Jun-01-20', 'May-29-20', 'May-15-20', 'May-11-20', 'May-08-20', 'Apr-02-20', 'Feb-28-20', 'Feb-24-20', 'Feb-18-20', 'Feb-13-20', 'Jan-19-20', 'Jan-17-20']
```

Not sure how to go about this or if it's even possible as each page I scrape results in different elements in the list having 'None'. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Python 3.8+, you can use assignment expression:

```
dates = ['Jun-29-20', 'None', 'None', 'Jun-27-20', 'Jun-26-20', 'None', 'Jun-24-20', 'Jun-22-20', 'None', 'Jun-17-20', 'Jun-16-20', 'None', 'Jun-15-20', 'None', 'None', 'Jun-01-20', 'None', 'May-29-20', 'May-15-20', 'May-11-20', 'May-08-20', 'Apr-02-20', 'Feb-28-20', 'Feb-24-20', 'Feb-18-20', 'Feb-13-20', 'Jan-19-20', 'Jan-17-20']

dates = [current:=d if d != 'None' else current for d in dates]

print(dates)
```

Prints:

```
['Jun-29-20', 'Jun-29-20', 'Jun-29-20', 'Jun-27-20', 'Jun-26-20', 'Jun-26-20', 'Jun-24-20', 'Jun-22-20', 'Jun-22-20', 'Jun-17-20', 'Jun-16-20', 'Jun-16-20', 'Jun-15-20', 'Jun-15-20', 'Jun-15-20', 'Jun-01-20', 'Jun-01-20', 'May-29-20', 'May-15-20', 'May-11-20', 'May-08-20', 'Apr-02-20', 'Feb-28-20', 'Feb-24-20', 'Feb-18-20', 'Feb-13-20', 'Jan-19-20', 'Jan-17-20']
```

Comment: I like this answer but I'm not sure I understand the logic. Could you please elaborate on how it works? I don't understand how the assignment expression is identifying the previous element in the list

Comment: @prime90 In the `if` expression, I check if the current element is equal to `None`. If not, then I save this element to value `current`. If yes, I use the value of `current`. So the value `current` always contains the last non-`None` element.

Comment: `d` is assigned to a holding variable, `current`. `d` from dates gets added to the new list unless it is 'None'. If `d` is 'None' then `current` is added to the new list. Incidentally, `current` is always the previous value of `d`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Nice answer +10

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
list(pd.to_datetime(dates, errors='coerce').to_series().ffill())
```

Output:

```
[Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-27 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-26 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-26 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-22 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-22 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-17 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-16 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-16 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-15 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-15 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-15 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-15 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-08 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-04-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-02-28 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-02-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-02-18 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-01-19 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-01-17 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: I think`.fillna(method='ffill')` looks a bit better. Also it works on serieses so you will not need the `.to_frame()` and `[0]`.

Comment: @Yonlif `pd.to_datetime(some_list)` returns an index object, not series, so `fillna` might not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `functools.reduce` to loop through and replace `'None'` strings with the previous value (`acc[-1]` in the example):

```
import functools


dates = ['Jun-29-20', 'None', 'None', 'Jun-27-20', 'Jun-26-20', 'None', 'Jun-24-20', 'Jun-22-20', 'None', 'Jun-17-20', 'Jun-16-20', 'None', 'Jun-15-20', 'None', 'None', 'Jun-01-20', 'None', 'May-29-20', 'May-15-20', 'May-11-20', 'May-08-20', 'Apr-02-20', 'Feb-28-20', 'Feb-24-20', 'Feb-18-20', 'Feb-13-20', 'Jan-19-20', 'Jan-17-20']


result = functools.reduce(lambda acc, val: acc + [acc[-1]] if val == 'None' else acc + [val], dates, [])

print(result)
```